# Rubyonrails-How to do scaffolding for a already existing model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, scaffolding

I already have a model named profile and corresponding database table profiles.
Now i would like to create crud operations for this profile model using SCAFFOLDING.
how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with Replico's answer. But if you really want to use scaffold you could use:

`rails generate scaffold_controller NAME`

so for you:

`rails generate scaffold_controller Profile`

see

`rails generate scaffold_controller --help`

for details.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest creating the CRUD operations from scratch rather than using scaffold. It'll improve your rails development skills and you don't have to worry about unnecessary generated code from the scaffold - create a sample scaffold if you like to give you a basis to work from.

Alternatively you could 'destroy' the model and recreate in a scaffold, that wont take long at all.